# MVC OnActionExecuted - session cookie - expire after x minutes of inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm creating a session cookie which should expire after 30 minutes of user inactivity. I've added the following code to the controllers OnActionExecuted method.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var sessionCookie = Request.Cookies[COOKIE_VALUE];

        if (sessionCookie == null)
        {
            sessionCookie = new HttpCookie(COOKIE_VALUE)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
            };

            sessionCookie.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            sessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        }

        Response.Cookies.Add(sessionCookie);

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

As this is happening every time a request is made, would this cookie update be noticeable in regards to speed? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/